# In Android portrait mode google vision Camera Source preview has padding

Tags: android, qr-code, barcode-scanner, google-vision, image-scanner

I am Using Google vision API and developing BARcodes/QRcodes scanning APP. I am also trying to use Overlay to make the scanning square area. But when I am trying to execute I am getting some margin space at right side of the screen, though I provided only Match-parent for both height and weight. Sometimes while rotating the screen looks fine but the camera focus is somewhat Elongated.

```
   public CameraSourcePreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mContext = context;
    mStartRequested = false;
    mSurfaceAvailable = false;

    mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
    mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceCallback());
    addView(mSurfaceView);
}

@RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
public void start(CameraSource cameraSource) throws IOException, SecurityException {
    if (cameraSource == null) {
        stop();
    }

    mCameraSource = cameraSource;

    if (mCameraSource != null) {
        mStartRequested = true;
        startIfReady();
    }
}

@RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
public void start(CameraSource cameraSource, GraphicOverlay overlay) throws IOException, SecurityException {
    mOverlay = overlay;
    start(cameraSource);
}

public void stop() {
    if (mCameraSource != null) {
        mCameraSource.stop();
    }
}

public void release() {
    if (mCameraSource != null) {
        mCameraSource.release();
        mCameraSource = null;
    }
}

@RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
private void startIfReady() throws IOException, SecurityException {
    if (mStartRequested && mSurfaceAvailable) {
        mCameraSource.start(mSurfaceView.getHolder());
        if (mOverlay != null) {
            Size size = mCameraSource.getPreviewSize();
            int min = Math.min(size.getWidth(), size.getHeight());
            int max = Math.max(size.getWidth(), size.getHeight());
            if (isPortraitMode()) {
                // Swap width and height sizes when in portrait, since it will be rotated by
                // 90 degrees
                mOverlay.setCameraInfo(min, max, mCameraSource.getCameraFacing());
            } else {
                mOverlay.setCameraInfo(max, min, mCameraSource.getCameraFacing());
            }
            mOverlay.clear();
        }
        mStartRequested = false;
   }
}

private class SurfaceCallback implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surface) {
        mSurfaceAvailable = true;
        try {
            startIfReady();
        } catch (SecurityException se) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Do not have permission to start the camera", se);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not start camera source.", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surface) {
        mSurfaceAvailable = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    }
}

@Override
protected void onLayout (boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
{
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();

    if (mCameraSource != null) {
        Size size = mCameraSource.getPreviewSize();
        if (size != null) {
            width = size.getWidth();
            height = size.getHeight();
        }
    }

    int layoutWidth = right - left;
    int layoutHeight = bottom - top;

    // Swap width and height sizes when in portrait, since it will be rotated 90 degrees
    if (isPortraitMode()) {
        int tmp = width;
        //noinspection SuspiciousNameCombination
        width = height;
        height = tmp;
    }

    int childWidth = layoutWidth;
    int childHeight = (int) (((float) layoutWidth / (float) width) * height);
  if (isPortraitMode()) {

        childHeight = layoutHeight;
        childWidth = (int) (((float) layoutHeight / (float) height) * width);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); ++i) {
      getChildAt(i).layout(0, 0, childWidth, childHeight);
    }

    try {
        startIfReady();
    } catch (SecurityException se) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Do not have permission to start the camera", se);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not start camera source.", e);
    }
}

/*@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    int width = 320;
    int height = 240;
    if (mCameraSource != null) {
        Size size = mCameraSource.getPreviewSize();
        if (size != null) {
            width = size.getWidth();
            height = size.getHeight();
        }
    }

    // Swap width and height sizes when in portrait, since it will be rotated 90 degrees
 if (isPortraitMode()) {
        int tmp = width;
        //noinspection SuspiciousNameCombination
        width = height;
        height = tmp;
    }

    final int layoutWidth = right - left;
    final int layoutHeight = bottom - top;

    // Computes height and width for potentially doing fit width.
    int childWidth = layoutWidth;
    int childHeight = (int) (((float) layoutWidth / (float) width) * height);

    // If height is too tall using fit width, does fit height instead.
    if (childHeight > layoutHeight) {
        childHeight = layoutHeight;
        childWidth = (int) (((float) layoutHeight / (float) height) * width);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); ++i) {
        getChildAt(i).layout(0, 0, childWidth, childHeight);
    }

    try {
        startIfReady();
    } catch (SecurityException se) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Do not have permission to start the camera", se);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not start camera source.", e);
    }
}*/

private boolean isPortraitMode() {
    int orientation = mContext.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        return false;
    }
    if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        return true;
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "isPortraitMode returning false by default");
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: I have included the **CameraSourcePreview**  code.